# Reload chat content without press f5

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a little chat with PHP. Everything works fine but the chat doesn't reload automatically. Is there a function that would solve my problem?

My PHP-Code:

```
<?php
  $newmsg= mysqli_query($db_chat, "SELECT msg, username, time FROM messages");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($newmsg))
  {
      echo '<div class="messagesinchat">';
        if ($row->username == "admin") {
          echo '<div class="ownmsg">';
          echo $row->username. ":&nbsp " . $row->msg;
          echo "<br />";
          echo '</div>';
        }
        else{
          echo $row->username. ":&nbsp" . $row->msg;
          echo "<br />";
        }
      echo '</div>';
  }
    ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, you either need a websocket or use js/jQuery to do that, php by default doesn't do anything once it's done executing the first time.

Comment: That's wonderful. Could you try something first?

Comment: You need Ajax to do this in real-time.

Comment: Pusher is quite good for something like this also as it keeps it realtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your `div` in your display page, and, you could use jQuery's `.load()` to load the chat messages into the `div` using a PHP script. Then, every x seconds, reload your `div`.

Let's say you have: 
`display.php` to actually, well.. display your chat. (`<div id='messagesinchat`> should be here.

In `display.php`, have the jQuery like:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#messagesinchat').load('chat.php?action=show');
    }, 1000);
});
```

In `chat.php?action=show` you execute the queries to search and print your messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a page reload after a few seconds as per your need.

```
<script>
 setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.reload(1);
 }, 5000);
</script>
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://yoursite.com/chat.php">
```

Comment: The whole page is reloading with your code. But I just want to reload this single div.

Comment: For that requirement, you need to use  ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP:

`header("Refresh:0");`

See Peter Mortensen's answer on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383371/refresh-a-page-using-php)