# PHP Redirect for 5 seconds, then return back to originating page

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and have been attempting to write a simple PHP script that will is activated from a "submit" button.

1. Show a "Welcome message"
2. Redirect to a an external page for 5 seconds, then return to the script.
3. Show a "Thank you"

So far I've tried:

```
<?php
echo 'Welcome to ......'; 
header( "refresh:5;url=what.html" ); 
?>
```

Any suggestions? At the moment it justs redirects after 5 seconds, and I need to return back to a "Thank you prompt"

Comment: Currently the destination page doesn't have the redirect after five seconds, does it?. You either do it in an iframe/modal, or place the a redirect after five seconds at the destination page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383371/refresh-a-page-using-php

Comment: Once the user lands on the redirected page, after a 5 second delay it needs to send them back to the original script. This is not just a simple page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to send the headers **before** doing any output! You also may use HTML Tags to do the redirection.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=/what.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Welcome to ......</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't code on same page 'source.html' to redirect on 'destination.html' for 5 minutes only.

For that you have to first redirect to 'destination.html' and there you have to add code to return back to 'source.html' page after 5 seconds.

Comment: I see what you mean. Perhaps the suggestion of using a modal which displays the webpage for 5 seconds - then closes is the way to go, but its a bit out of my depth at the moment.

Comment: the steps then require would be - redirect to a page with a modal containing the webpage . show it for 5 secs - then close it.