# Refresh page when new data updated in DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, refresh

I want my PHP to automatically refresh the page **when data in the DB is updated**. Is this possible with only PHP & HTML? Or do I need JS?
Example: A status of an emergency vehicle changed. Then the coordinator of these vehicles should see it withoud refreshing the page

I tried it this way, but it didn't work:

```
while ($row['einsatz'] != 0){
                $sql = "SELECT `status` FROM `Fahrzeuglisten` WHERE `id` = 1";
                foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {}
                if ($_SESSION["st11"] != $row['status']){
                    echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'/>";
                }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh a page using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383371/refresh-a-page-using-php)

Comment: The sql are going to be inserted without php? or you want to get the update on the current page if another user add some data?

Comment: Did you mean a real time database functionality using php and mysql

Comment: The Data is added by an other user.

Comment: You can use AJAX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch real-time/live count of any php mysql row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676172/how-to-fetch-real-time-live-count-of-any-php-mysql-row)