# can not refresh page after sending file

Tags: php

I am newbie with PHP and backend

below codes send a file to client

```
$size = strlen($data);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$name}");
header("Content-Length: $size");
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    header('Pragma: ');
    header('Cache-Control: ');
} else {
    header("Pragma: private");
    header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate");
}
```

here I want to reload page after download file

I've tried below code But it didn't work

```
header('Refresh: 0;');
```

so How can I reload/refresh page after download finished ?

Comment: You cannot do it that way. This simply is not possible by a purely server side solution. You have two options: both require client side logic: 1. download the file by an extra request done via ajax, triggered by the client side. When that request is done the client can decide to refresh the still loaded page. 2. refresh the loaded page blindly after a certain period of time, this also has to be triggered by a client side logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh a page using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383371/refresh-a-page-using-php)

Comment: no , sorry    it is not